# TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not Settings

Tags: python, pygame

I am working through the Alien Invasion program and I am stuck with the fire bullet section. The error message I kept getting when I press space is shown above in the title. The codes that I hvae written are shown as below. I did what the tutorial says and seperated the codes into different files and called them in the main code. I think there is problems with the bullets.add(new_bullet)bit in the game_functions.py file but I can't see any difference between my codes and the codes in the book. Also I am not entirely sure what the sprite module does. The book didn't really go into details about the function of the sprite module.

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings,screen)
    bullets = Group()

    # start the main loop for the game
    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)


run_game()
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event,ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)

def fire_bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):        
    if len(bullets)< ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event,ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()           
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event,ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    bullets.update()
    bullets.update()
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def _init_(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
        super(Bullet,self)._init_()
        self.screen = screen

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,ai_settings.bullet_width,
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        ptgame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.color,self.rect)
```

settings.py

```
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
        #bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60,60,60
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: The name of a constructor has to be  `__init__` not `_init_`: Thus you have to change the name in the class `Bullet:` `def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, it's working now.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at the question! Much appericiated.

Comment: What are all the libraries you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The name of a constructor has to be `__init__` not `_init_`. Thus you have to change the name in the class Bullet:

<s>`def _init_(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):`</s>

```py
def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
```